# How to install Apache Directory Studio in Eclipse Neon

Tags: ldap, eclipse-neon, apache-directory

I cannot find how to install Apache Directory Studio under Eclipse Neon. It looks like this project requires an update. Do you have more information about this?

Regards
Ignacio

Comment: Are you getting errors? What are they. It isn't clear what you're asking.

Comment: There is a change in the p2 format and it looks like Mars version cannot be installed on Neon

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I installed Neon alongside Luna, then, as usual I did a File -> Import -> From existing installation. That installation failed for almost all packages. Then I tried to find Apache under the Eclipse Installer window and could not see anything. Finally I decided to add a new site and use the URL  http://directory.apache.org/studio/update and that worked fine.